# South Korea travel visa

Tags: visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, south-korea, sri-lankan-citizens

Can I use my wife's bank statement to apply for the South Korea tourist visa. my wife and daughter travel with me.

Comment: Can you edit this to clarify. You ask about your wife's bank statement but then say your husband is travelling with you.

Comment: Can you also include your (and your spouse and daughter's nationality.

Comment: @mdewey ok sorry  i will edit it.

Comment: @Willeke Srilankan

Comment: Who is paying the costs of the trip?